# Camera: Not working or all pictures gray

Tags: camera

I'm having some serious troubles with my android camera application.

Either it directly tells me that it's not working ("Camera failed" in WhatsApp), or it allows me to take a picture - but that picture is just a full gray image with some stains on it (looks a little like this https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/119/257/large_2x/gray-paper-texture-background-vector.jpg  for instance). However, through the "viewfinder" everything looks perfect - so the camera hardware itself should be fine.

**My guess:**
The SD card is damaged. I can't download any pictures from my web browser or send / receive images via WhatsApp (or any other app). 
But, I *CAN* access the files on the SD card, so there is also some evidence against a corrupted SD card.

**Details:**
Phone: Lenovo K6
OS: Android 6.0

Comment: The link you posted gives an "access denied" error. You could [edit] your question and upload an actual picture you've taken if that's easier than describing it.

Comment: @elasticman Stackoverflow allows to upload images. Please edit your question and upload/include the image into your post. Please don't use images that are hosted externally.

Comment: The link is now working - I can't upload any image from the phone, as I can't see the picture in the gallery. I will try to capture it with a second camera.